# How to increase max body/connection size in NSoup

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, jsoup

I am rewriting a Java program in C#. I used the XML parse JSoup, and I'd like to use the .NET port NSoup. However, I cannot find the replacement for

```
source=Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").maxBodySize(2097152).get(); //2MB limit
```

Visual Studio tells me "NSoup.IConnection does not contain a definition for "MaxBodySize". And it doesn't. I've looked through the source code at http://nsoup.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NSoup/IConnection.cs and I can't find where the ported method is.

Can this be solved? The ultimate goal is being able to increase the default limit (the source I get is garbage because it can't download all the data) because the default is too low.

Comment: Not familiar with NSoup, but shouldn't `http://www.example.com` be enclosed in quotes to represent a string: `"http://www.example.com"`?

Comment: yes, I just typed it. I assure you this was not my problem though :)

Comment: Yeah, just a side note ;)